# Using Python3.x , in nano, the first line cannot be edited

Tags: python, python-3.x, nano

In Python3, using nano, the very first line I create somehow gets "tabbed" over about several characters. This does not happen when the source code is initially created. E.g. the program can contain only one line, a simple:

```
print ("Hello World")
```

Once you save and you re-enter the program, it looks like this (moved to the right several spaces)on the first line:

```
                                          print ("Hello World")
```

A 'cat' on the program does not show the first line "tabbing". The line is left justified (i.e., it looks normal). The program runs fine and without errors. It is important to note that re-entering the source in nano OR vi subsequently makes that first line totally disabled and it cannot be edited.  What is possibly causing this?

Comment: Please specify your OS and include an _exact_ sequence of steps that can _reproducibly_ lead to your problem. Clearly, the problem has nothing to do with Python 3.x, and probably with Python in general, either.

Comment: I cannot reproduce. Used nano to create file with that content, reopened in vim and nano no issues. Mac High Sierra.

Comment: So, did this happen just once? The fact it did show the line indented maybe was simply you indenting the line by mistaking (but I dunno whether `nano` can do that with a shortcut...). The fact that the file afterwards looks normal maybe it's simply you forgetting to save the modifications of the file. I've never seen a line not being editable in vim, so I have no idea what you are talking about...

Comment: If the issue if with the contents of the file you should really post here the contents of the file. Unfortunately if you paste the text SO is going to remove/replace some characters and may hide the issue. Do this `print(open("/path/to/file", "rb").read())` so that you can paste the escaped contents

Comment: anything in your .nanorc?

Comment: OS is Linux 4.9.35+ on a raspberry Pi. Python3 is v3.4.2.  ..Step(s) 1-create a new file,2-Insert .....print ("Hello World"). 3-Save. 4-renter in nano. 5-try to edit that one line,. It cannot be edited. The ability to add lines below it is OK. 6-cancel and run hello.py. It runs fine.  .... It happens in all programs I have created. .......I save via CTRL+O, ENTER,CTRL+X......I do not use vim, it is not installed. However, vi is installed and working. Even in vi that first line cannot be edited. It is a totally disabled line. Any lines below it are fully editable (same as in nano). ...

Comment: include /usr/share/nano/asm.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/awk.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/cmake.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/c.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/css.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/debian.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/fortran.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/gentoo.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/groff.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/html.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/java.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/makefile.nanorc

Comment: include /usr/share/nano/makefile.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/man.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/mgp.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/mutt.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/nanorc.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/objc.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/ocaml.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/patch.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/perl.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/php.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/pov.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/python.nanorc

Comment: include /usr/share/nano/ruby.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/sh.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/tcl.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/tex.nanorc
include /usr/share/nano/xml.nanorc

# tabs to spaces for PYTHON
set tabsize 4
set tabstospaces